# PostgreSQL, не могу скачать с оффициального сайта(vpn не помогает)

Tags: postgresql

я начинающий разработчик в Node.js, пытался скачать БД PosgreSQL с оффициального сайта (https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/), но мне при попытке скачать появляется следующее уведомление

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал обойти эту проблему используя vpn, однако результат оказался тем же.
Подскажите, где можно скачать эту БД без вирусов (пожалуйста скиньте ссылку)?

Comment: https://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-15.4-1-windows-x64.exe

Comment: @Akina, благодарю вас